# How to keep an activity in foreground for 15 seconds and then dismiss it?

Tags: android, handler

I need to start an activity at time 0, keep it in the foreground for 15 seconds and then stop the activity. What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
int duration = 15000; // milliseconds

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
}, duration);
```

This will automatically finish your activity after 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AlarmManager` to call the activity back in fifteen seconds, an example of using `AlarmManager` can be seen here: http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/.

The `BroadcastReciever` that is called should be inside the main `Activity` and it should call `finish()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a `splashActivity` :

```
 public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

        private static final int DURATION = 15000; // 15 seconds


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

            Handler handler = new Handler();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {     
                    finish();

                }

            }, DURATION);

        }
}
```

You can see [here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ch/2012/06/android-simple-splash-screen.html) a full working example.